# Select a range of cells and perform multiple merge functions using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge, automation

I'm pretty new to google sheets and this is my first google script.
I need to select a range of cells (B3:K22) and send as an email (GmailApp.sendEmail()). I need to merge a few cells of different ranges while sending the mail However, when I run the script, the merged cells are getting unmerged in the mail. I believe the mergeAcross() is not getting applied. Below is my code:

```
enter code here

function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var recipient = "xx@xx.com"; // "TO" email address
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  var schedRange =  sheet.getRange('B3:K22'); 
  sheet.getRange('B3:F3').activate().mergeAcross();
  sheet.getRange('G3:K3').activate().mergeAcross();
  sheet.getRange('B4:F4').activate().mergeAcross();
  sheet.getRange('C14:D14').activate().mergeAcross();
  sheet.getRange('G13:K13').activate().mergeAcross();  
  sheet.getRange('B3:F3').activate().mergeAcross();
  var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">'
  body += '<H1>'+ sheet.getRange("B3").getValue() +'</H1>';
  body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);
  body += '</div>';
  debugger;

  recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  // For debugging, send only to self
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body})
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are hoping to receive, and what are you actually receiving?

Comment: Do not merge cells.